# EMC foundation certification -Exam prerequisits

Tags: storage, emc

I 've been working as SAN support engineer for 7 months ,now.I want to go for EMC foundation certification,which ,i believe , is essential in order to progress in my career.

Can somebody advise  me if i can take up the certification (foundation) with 7-8 months of experience.
And ,do i need to cover Cisco/brocade switches as well?

Any good link related to preparing for the certification will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on your question and your comments below mfinni's answer, I recommend you take a a little time to learn how to research. Without decent research, which includes reading the document linked to, you can expect studying to be a lot harder and less fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](http://education.emc.com/content/_common/docs/exam_descriptions/e20_040_EMC_Technology_Foundations_exam.pdf) on their site clearly details what technologies can be on the exam. Cisco and Brocade are not terms found in that document. As to your level of experience, I'd say (as with almost all things) it depends. If you've spent 7 months doing nothing but configuring Clariions and HBAs, you're probably going to do poorly on any VMware and Networker questions.

Comment: @mfinni which document you 're referring to?

Comment: thanks for the document..can i get access to the video ILT and e-learning program mentioned in their doc..

Do i have to learn celerra and symmetrix also? since i have only worked on Clariion.
Any body who has done this certification ,please help

Comment: I would suggest that you go to the emc.com site, view Training and Education, and look up the resources available there. That single PDF is not going to answer all of your questions, it just tells you where to start. And yes, Celerra and Symmetrix are (wait for it) *right there in the document.*